# PostgreSQL - Delete duplicated records - ERROR: too many range table entries

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb, hypertable

I have a HyperTable (TimescaleDB extension) called "conferimenti"

I am trying to delete about 2500 duplicated rows

```
DELETE FROM conferimenti
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT id
    FROM 
        (SELECT id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY dataora, idcomune, codicestazione, tiporifiuto, codicetag
        ORDER BY  id ) AS row_num
        FROM conferimenti ) t
        WHERE t.row_num > 1);
```

throws an error
**ERROR:  too many range table entries**
SQL state: 54000

Executing this query i have a one column "id" with all the ids

```
SELECT id
    FROM 
        (SELECT id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY dataora, idcomune, codicestazione, tiporifiuto, codicetag
        ORDER BY  id ) AS row_num
        FROM conferimenti ) t
        WHERE t.row_num > 1
```

I cannot disable triggers

Answer (score 1):

The [sql state](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html) 5400 is for a "program limit exceeded", but there is nothing specifically for "ERROR: too many range table entries". Further you indicate that you "cannot disable triggers" which leads to the conclusion this is an internally generated application error; not a Postgres generated error. Seems like someone has established a **Business Rule** limiting the number of deletes. You need to investigate and determine that limit. Then revise you delete state to delete no more that that value.

```
DELETE FROM conferimenti
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT id
    FROM 
        (SELECT id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY dataora, idcomune, codicestazione, tiporifiuto, codicetag
        ORDER BY  id ) AS row_num
        FROM conferimenti ) t
   WHERE t.row_num > 1
   LIMIT <business_rule_max> );
```

Then run it multiple times as needed.